# Does SuperOneClick flash a kernel?

Tags: rooting, samsung-galaxy-s-2

Does [SuperOneClick](http://shortfuse.org/?page_id=2) need to flash a kernel to the phone to root it, thus incrementing the custom kernel counter in the Samsung Galaxy S2?

Answer (score 2):

[Yes, it seems so](http://shortfuse.org/?p=61):

> Many (but not all) Galaxy SII are supported by installing a patched kernel.